# No tengo la opción de Aplicación de consola win32 en visual studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2017

quería saber por qué no me aparece en Visual Studio 2017 la plantilla de Aplicación de consola Win32 de C++. Hace un par de semanas lo tenía y podía abrirlo tranquilamente. Pero ayer, no sé por qué no me aparece más, solo me aparecen *Proyecto vacío*, *Aplicación de escritorio de Windows* y *Aplicación de consola de Windows*

Muchas gracias.

Versiones de .NET Framework que me aparecen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Asegúrate que tengas seleccionada la versión de .Net framework adecuada. Quizá la selección habitual cambió y no soporta las aplicaciones de consola la nueva versión seleccionada

Comment: La verdad no sé si tengo la versión de .NET Framework adecuada. Edité la publicación mostrando las versiones de .NET Framework que tengo. Si no es de mucha molestia, podría decirme si las que tengo, alguna es la adecuada? En caso de que no sea así, como podría obtenerla?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no has instalado la opción para compilar C++ nativo. Únicamente has instalado el soporte para .Net y por eso las únicas opciones que te ofrece son las que te permiten crear aplicaciones para esta plataforma.

Modifica las opciones de instalación para que se instalen las opciones correspondientes al montaje nativo con C++. Después no olvides instalar el SDK de windows correspondiente para evitar problemas al generar los ejecutables.

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, busqué a que se refería con C++ nativo y solo me apareció para compilarlo y no la opción. Acá le dejo un screen que le hice a las unicas opciones marcadas que tengo. Lo que está en componentes individuales no tengo idea la verdad si tengo que tocar alguna de esas. Gracias
https://prnt.sc/h3nxss